# Why jQuery ajax function not working in IOS browsers devices

Tags: jquery, ajax

i make function to send Google form using ajax, it's working in Desktop and Android browsers but it's not working at IOS browsers , Any Help ?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="googleformContactresponde" id="googleformContactrespondeID"></div>

<form action="" method="post" id="ss-form" onsubmit="return done();">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="entry.1899579046" minlength="3" required="" aria-required="true" type="text">
        <div class="errorchick" id="c_name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="entry.1718424446" required="" aria-required="true" type="email"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="entry.1228435843" minlength="3" maxlength="25" required="" aria-required="true"
         type="text"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="msg" name="entry.1329820139" minlength="3" maxlength="500" required=""
         aria-required="true"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="form-slider-status"></div>
        <button type="submit" id="form-slider-submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function done() {
        var c_name = jQuery("#name").val();
        if (c_name == "") {
            jQuery("#c_name").show().html("please enter the name");
            setTimeout(function () {
                jQuery("#c_name").hide()
            }, 2000);
            jQuery("#name").focus(); return false;
        } else {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "urlsubmit",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache: false,
                data: { "entry.1899579046": jQuery("#name").val(), "entry.1718424446": jQuery("#email").val(), "entry.1228435843": jQuery("#phone").val(), "entry.1329820139": jQuery("#msg").val(), "entry.396737882": jQuery("#hide").val() },
                success: function (response) { alert("success"); }
            });
            jQuery("#ss-form")[0].reset();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

live test : https://www.judran-eg.com/en/property/midtown-sky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix this issue ,it's about redirect to another page i set timeout function to delay redirection to make sure that form is submit .

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.href="'.$url.'";  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your all jQuery code on this block :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 // your code
 init();
});
```

Comment: thanks for trying help me but it's also not working @Amir